# select 2 columns from 2 tables using a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables, Table1 has a column called book names and many other columns while table table 2 has 2 columns only- all book names and no of pages.
The number of book names used in Table1 is smaller than table2. There is no id column so has to be joined by book name.
All the books named in Table.2 are not used in table.1, it has a smaller subset.
I am trying to 
select table1.book name, table2.noOfPages
from table.1
inner join on book name

Though there are only 100000 rows in table 1 and 7000 rows in table2,the  query returns 200000 rows! I expect the result to match the number of rows in table.1
Not sure what I am doing wrong?
Can someone help please?
Thanks
Suzy

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are using.

Comment: There are  duplicates in table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`, something like:

```
select t1.bookname, t2.noOfPages
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.bookname = t2.bookname;
```

You may get *more* results than in `table1` if there are duplicates in `table2`.  You can find these by doing:

```
select t2.bookname
from table2 t2
group by t2.bookname
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my attention, the duplicates was the issue and the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

One way is `MAX` with `GROUP BY` to return the expected output with no duplicate values but it may return wrong number of pages due to `MAX` in the query so if it's fine then leave it otherwise find the duplicates and correct it

```
SELECT t1.bookname, t2.noOfPages
FROM (SELECT bookname, MAX(noOfPages) AS noOfPages 
      FROM table2
      GROUP BY bookname) t2  
INNER JOIN  table1 t1 ON t1.bookname = t2.bookname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use an INNER JOIN to get the pairs only. ie. The union of A and B, where A is table1, and B is table2.

example. 

SELECT t1.BookName, t2.noOfPages 
FROM Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.BookName = t2.BookName
```

Perhaps the missing piece is the key link, or maybe there are duplicate names in either table, it will be hard to tell since there is no primary key and foreign key. Maybe try using DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.BookName, t2.noOfPages 
FROM Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.BookName = t2.BookName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.bookname, t2.noOfPages
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.bookname = t2.bookname
-- and t1.bookname like '%martin%' -- do not filter here
where t1.bookname like '%martin%'; -- filter conditions ALWAYS in where
```

Never filter your data in `join`-condition. It is very slow. Add filters in `where`-part. This way your data is reduced before the db connects the tables.